How to get the named range definition in Cell
Suppose I have a named Range in Googlesheets as MyNamedRange with definition as C1:H25
Now In a cell I want to show this value in cell A1 as "C1:H25"
Is it possible through some formula like MyNamedRange.getText or something like same.
Not interested in Google Apps Script to use for this.
I tried using To_Text(NamedRange) but go error.

Use the ADDRESS function.

I can see how you could use Address with index or offset to get the beginning and end of the named range, but I can't think of a way of finding out if it's absolute or relative - not without comparing two different cells to see if it's changed.

same logic should work in sheets as well. Just disregard the @ character within the formula when implementing.

Ah so my comment is wrong on all counts. There is no such thing as an absolute or relative reference in a named range in google sheets (unlike Excel). They are entered without $ signs but behave like absolute references. Also no need to use index or offset with Address. I don't mind - I have learnt something. See https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4380342/named-range-saves-as-relative-not-absolute?hl=en

CELL
Using the CELL function returns absolute references, $A$1
=CELL("address", INDEX(rngName,1,1))& ":" & 
 CELL("address", INDEX(rng Name, ROWS(rngName), COLUMNS(rngName))))

ADDRESS
Using the ADDRESS function allows you to specify one of four options for its absolute_relative_mode argument, $A$1, A$1, $A1, A1
=ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(rngName,1)), COLUMN(INDEX(rngName,,1)),4) &":"& 
 ADDRESS(ROWS(rngName), COLUMNS(rngName),4)) 

